# File object is null for Camel Exchange getbody

Tags: apache-camel, apache-httpcomponents

In my camel route i am trying to get file object.

```
rest("/file")
    .post("/extract")
    .to("direct:extract");
    from("direct:extract")
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
             File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
             LOG.info("file : "+file);
     multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA,filename));

        }
        })
```

Here from rest  i'm sending file, in processor when i tried to get through exchange getBody i'm getting as null.
But same thing if i try to fetch Inputstream and byte[] means its working fine.

```
    byte[] bytes = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
    LOG.info("bytes : "+bytes);
    InputStream is = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
```

my goal is to fetch file object from exchange getBody ,is any thing wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   .to("direct:extract");

    from("direct:extract")

    .setBody().simple("${body}")
    .to("http4://....")
    .end();
```

you don't need to convert it into Byte[] or inputstream,you can directly pass it as a body and then set it as a body

Answer (score 2):

There is no `java.io.File` as the message body, as a HTTP file upload is not represented as a `java.io.File` but as an input stream instead. The `java.io.File` is for the regular file component in Camel.

Comment: Thank you , i will try with input stream.

Comment: I tried with inputstream also but i am not able get response and i send file from POST like above code for that  i am not getting  file object/inputstream/bytes[] , if i send file through path like :- from("file:E:/folder4/pdfReceipt?noop=true") i able to get response.

Comment: Now i am able to upload pdf,txt files using byte[] format  but the same code is not working for image files(.jpg,.png),not able to upload image files.

Comment: Can you check if the Content-Type of the HTTP header is set to a correct type when you use images vs other kind of files.

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried  multipart/form-data as a consumes(multipart/form-data) for all types of files and  its working now.